# ComboBox KeyDown event how to take into account last pressed key

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, keydown

I have an editable combobox and have to handle the entered value (it has to be a number).
In the keydown event I analyze combobox.text and act accordingly.
Of course in this case combobox.text shall have all the text prior to the keydown event. Instead I want the final complete text key down included.

I have tried to put

```
e.handled=true;
```

before analyzing combobox.text but that didn't work.

As an secondary solution I analyze e.key and have to transform it into a string and cope with it. The problem is that it's a keyeventargs.
Have tried that

```
char ch ;
String str;
if (e.Key > Key.D0 && e.Key < Key.D9)
{
  ch = (char)((int)e.Key - (int)Key.D0);
  str = ch.ToString();
}
```

but it didn't work

---ADD---
Sorry my bad for not having made it clear I'll try to make it better.
I want to work on my combobox in the following event

```
private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
```

and inside I want to do something like

```
Analyze(combobox.text)
```

so in short

```
private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if((e.Key > Key.D0 && e.Key < Key.D9) || (e.Key > Key.NumPad0 && e.Key < Key.NumPad9))
  {
    Analyze(comboBox.text)---->text here has to be the combobox.text plus the new pressed key 
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot read what character user inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear what "act accordingly" means in your case, but try this instead for your secondary solution:

```
        string str = string.Empty;
        if (e.Key > Key.D0 && e.Key < Key.D9)
        {
            str = ((int)e.Key - (int)Key.D0).ToString();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Putting that in the ComboBox's keydown event returns the correct string for me, assuming correct means to get a string representation of the number key the user just pressed.

I'm really curious on what your end goal is. Perhaps elaborating on that would lead to better answers. Do you have to validate input at every key entered? Why?

Comment: You are right your comment is planting a seed of doubt. What I do is parsing the combobox.text and putting into an in variable. Is this logically wrong?

Comment: @Patrick It's not necessarily wrong. What else is in your UI? What's ideal is if there's a way that the user can use to tell you that they're done with input in the current screen. Something like an OK button, or if they have to press the return key to store the edit to the combobox. Then you can parse it at that event, saving a lot of continuous input processing. If you somehow must analyze at every key input... then you gotta do what you gotta do :).

Comment: This is an editable comboBox (I have lots in my program). The user can either choose a value from the combobox (those are default values) or type a new one.

Comment: The new one is acknodledged with the ComboBox_KeyDown event. When the event is fired therefore I check if it's a numeric and then I have to save in a variable the combobox text. But if  I do var = combobox.text it doesn't take into account the last key. So your solution comes in handy as a plan B. Plan A was something like "do something so that in automatically combobox.text has the pressed key" but perhaps it doesn't exists. Your solution anyhow solves the problem thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the solution proposed by Rowbear there is a simplier way to solve my problem. And that is use the ComboBox_KeyUp event. By doing that the new key already is aknowledged. My bad for having misleaded everyone by saying I wanted the key down. I added this only for sake of completeness

Answer (score 0):

I cannot completely understand what you want, but I'll try to do my best. If you want to read characters that are texted by user, it is more convenient to use event `PreviewTextInput`:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox" IsEditable="True" PreviewTextInput="comboBox_PreviewTextInput"/>
```

C#:

```
string theWholeString;
private void comboBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
   string currentCharacter = e.Text;
   theWholeString += e.Text;
}
```

It is better as you do not have to figure out whether input was number or string.

Let me know if I misunderstood you.